# I get the error saying "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" how do I fix this?

Tags: python, dictionary, openpyxl

```python
words = ['apple','bear','cinema']
dataset2 = ['apple','apple','bear','bear','pooh','cinema','cinema']
final_keys = {'apple':'a,b,c,d,b','bear':'s,q,d,f,d,s,d', 'cinema':'a,q,v,d,s,'}

for word in words:
    for i in range(len(dataset2)):        
        if word == str(dataset2[i]):
            datatocopy = final_keys[word]
            # above is where I get the error from

            load_ws[i+1,4] = str(datatocopy)
        else:
            continue
```

The above is part of my codes. I get the error saying `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.` from `datatocopy = final_keys[word]`. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and the line you mention throws errors works fine.
Here is what I tried :-

```
words = ['apple','bear','cinema']
dataset2 = ['apple','apple','bear','bear','pooh','cinema','cinema']
final_keys = {'apple':'a,b,c,d,b','bear':'s,q,d,f,d,s,d', 'cinema':'a,q,v,d,s,'}

for word in words:
    for i in range(len(dataset2)):        
        if word == str(dataset2[i]):
            datatocopy = final_keys[word]
            print("Values : ", datatocopy)
            # above is where I get the error from

            # load_ws[i+1,4] = str(datatocopy)
        else:
            continue
```

And here is the output :

```
Values :  a,b,c,d,b
Values :  a,b,c,d,b
Values :  s,q,d,f,d,s,d
Values :  s,q,d,f,d,s,d
Values :  a,q,v,d,s,
Values :  a,q,v,d,s,
```

Comment: oh actually above is part of my whole codes. I want to enter the "datatocopy" values to an excel file.....

Comment: You can use [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-excel-sheet-using-python/) guide to write to an excel.